# How to make an informational web site from a git repository

Tags: git, repository, generator

I would like to see some statistic and visual states of my git repository. Is there any nice tools around? I found http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/ but I would like to know if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git wiki [lists several web interfaces](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Web_Interface), and I doubt they've missed any significant ones.

Since you haven't specified what exactly you want to see as "visual states", it's hard to make any more specific of a recommendation.  Pretty much all the interfaces at least offer a branch view of sorts.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most spectacular:

**[Gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/)**

> software version control visualization tool.
>   Software projects are displayed by Gource as an animated  tree with:
>
> - the root directory of the project at its center,
> - directories appearing as branches with files as leaves.

Here is a snapshot of a flurry of development on the Linux project.

> As Linux is a huge C language project, the files being worked on are predominately a mix of `.c` (shown in green) and `.h` header files (in red).

[image: Gource example]